# fragment in the FragmentTabHost does not display

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

Really this is about multiple questions regarding using FragmentTabHost.
I found a working [sample](https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/android-styling-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/), which uses FragmentTabHost in Activity.
I need to use it in a Fragment.

It does display the fragment with tabs but the content fragment for the tab does not display. I saw the Log those content fragment's onCreateView() is indeed get called, but just does not shown on the screen.

1. I saw some one use a extra FrameLayout, I'm not sure why. But tried both way, does not help.
   and in the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html), it create FragmentTabHost instead get out from layout.
   So what is the right way to use FragmentTabHost?

   ```
   mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
   mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment1);
   ```
2. I tried same way to define the tab fragment layout (tab_fragment_layout.xml) as in the sample:

   ```
   <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TabWidget
       android:id="@android:id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

   <!-- why need it? -->
   <!-- with or without this @android:id/tabcontent FramLayout dosent work-->
   <!--FrameLayout
       android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0" /-->
   <!-- -->

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

The TabFragment::onCreateView() is:

```
TabFragment extends Fragment...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_layout, container, false);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),
            R.id.tabFrameLayout);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            ContentFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            ContentFragment.class, null);
    return view;
}
```

The content fragment is simple:

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

private String title = "no page data";
private int page = -1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(this.getTag() + " Content"+", page data:"+title+" "+page);
    return v;
}
}
```

Again, this is just porting the [sample](https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/android-styling-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/) (using it with in activity) to use it in fragment. But after adding this fragment in the activity, it only shows the tab without content fragment for each tab.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
TabFragment tabFrgmt = new TabFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.tab_fragment_holder, tabFrgmt);
ft.addToBackStack("theTabFragment");
ft.show(tabFrgmt);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this problem as well, I ended up using a component and getting better results. [Pager Sliding TabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

I wrote my case in Xamarin. But you might find the code useful.

```
    namespace project.Droid.Phone.Fragments
{
public class HostPageFragment : BaseFragment
{
    private ViewGroup _parentContainer;

    private LayoutInflater _inflater;

    private View _tabHostLayout;

    private HostPageViewModel _viewModel;


    public HostPageFragment(HostPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        _parentContainer = container;
        _inflater = inflater;

        _tabHostLayout = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HostPage, container, false);

        // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        var pager = _tabHostLayout.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);

        pager.Adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager,_viewModel);
        pager.SetCurrentItem(_viewModel.InitialTab,false);
        pager.OffscreenPageLimit = pager.Adapter.Count-1;

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        var tabs = _tabHostLayout.FindViewById<PagerSlidingTabStrip>(Resource.Id.tabs);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(_tabHostLayout.Context.Assets, "Fonts/CenturyGothicBold.ttf");
        tabs.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);

        tabs.SetViewPager(pager);

        return _tabHostLayout;

    }


}
public class MyPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private string[] Titles = {ApplicationResources.text, ApplicationResources.text, ApplicationResources.text};

    private HostPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, HostPageViewModel viewModel) : base(fm)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;

        Titles = _viewModel.BooleanFlag? Titles : Titles.Take(Titles.Length - 1).ToArray();
    }

    public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object @object)
    {
        container.RemoveView(@object as View);
        base.DestroyItem(container, position, @object);
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.String(Titles[position]);
    }
    #region implemented abstract members of PagerAdapter
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Titles.Length;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region implemented abstract members of FragmentPagerAdapter
    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                var vm = new ViewModel();
                //Initialization of Initial Tab is from the Hamubruger Menu and is used for HudService/Choosing first tab
                return new MyPageFragment(vm,_viewModel.InitialTab == position);
            case 1:
                var vm = new ViewModel();
                return new MyPageFragment(vm, _viewModel.InitialTab == position);
            case 2:
                var vm = new ViewModel();
                return new MyPageFragment(vm,_viewModel.InitialTab == position);
            default:
                //Incase we fall to default show the first tab
                var vm = new ViewModel();
                return new MyPageFragment(vm, _viewModel.InitialTab == position);
        }

    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zach. But still want to use FragmentTabHost in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel using FragmentTabHost is simpler than suing the slidingTab/ViewPager as long as don't care the swipe behavior.

For the #1. By looking at the code (in v4.app.FragmentTabHost of support-v4-21):

```
public void setup(Context context, FragmentManager manager, int containerId) {
    ensureHierarchy(context);  // Ensure views required by super.setup()
    super.setup();
    mContext = context;
    mFragmentManager = manager;
    mContainerId = containerId;
    ensureContent();
    mRealTabContent.setId(containerId);

    // We must have an ID to be able to save/restore our state.  If
    // the owner hasn't set one at this point, we will set it ourself.
    if (getId() == View.NO_ID) {
        setId(android.R.id.tabhost);
    }
}

private void ensureHierarchy(Context context) {
    // If owner hasn't made its own view hierarchy, then as a convenience
    // we will construct a standard one here.
    if (findViewById(android.R.id.tabs) == null) {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        addView(ll, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        TabWidget tw = new TabWidget(context);
        tw.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
        tw.setOrientation(TabWidget.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.addView(tw, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(context);
        fl.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        ll.addView(fl, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 0));

        mRealTabContent = fl = new FrameLayout(context);
        mRealTabContent.setId(mContainerId);
        ll.addView(fl, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 1));
    }
}
```

and the [bug report for FragmentTabHost](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53230), seems it could be done in one of the below:

```
  <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

or to mimc the ensureHierarchy() does.

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/alert_dialog_icon"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

For the problem of not showing the content fragment, after wrap the FragmentTabHost in another root layout it shows up.

But do have one question left, should be keep using support.v4 or change to the latest one like support.v7.app.FragmentTabHost, etc.?

Anyone has better solution or inside of what is the correct way using FragmentTabHost, please comment. Thanks!